# How to add frameworks in Xcode 8.3.3

Tags: xcode, swift3, import, xcode8, ios-frameworks

I'm having trouble adding a `Framework` I have in my local computer to my Xcode project. My intention is to import it as follows in my code:

```
import IOBubbles
```

This is a private framework, and it is not on the internet, CocoaPods, etc. I have tried this, so far:

**Attempt 1:**

```
File > Add files to "test-bubbles-project"
Selected directory for the IOBubbles.framework
```

That did not work.

**Attempt 2:**

I also tried:

```
Targets > Build Phases > Link Binary With Libraries > '+'
Add Other
Selected directory for the IOBubbles.framework
```

**Attempt 3:**

Then, I tried to go to `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks` and copy my framework to in there. I then imported from the `Developer Frameworks` folder. That did not work either.

**For all attempts:**

However, whenever I used

```
import IOBubbles
```

I got an error,

```
No such module 'IOBubbles'
```

I've looked at past questions attempting to address the same problem, however, I only found solutions for Xcode 4. I tried similar solutions above, but none of them worked. Please can you suggest how I should go about adding my framework by `import IOBubbles`, or any alternative which will allow me to use the classes/functions in the framework?

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm having this problem in C++ projects in Xcode 10

Comment: Hi @Andreas, unfortunately, I haven't.

Comment: I've stuck to using CocoaPods for my dependencies and all modules there. Do let me know if you find an alternative solution!